# Is there an MS Test Runner that is faster

Tags: unit-testing, performance, mstest

MS Test is killing me.

It is so slow compared to NUnit.  I am stuck with it because I need to be able to get Test Results into TFS easy.  (Plus it works better with Pex and I am using that too).

But I would really like it to go faster.  Even just a bit faster would be nice.

Has anyone made a test runner for MS Test tests that goes faster than the one embedded in Visual Studio?

Comment: I've read reports stating that MSTest creates bin folder copies for every test run.. as a result slowing down execution times. Check to see if there is a setting that turns this off.. Another option would be use the console runner for MSTest..

Answer (score 3):

The [**Gallio**](http://gallio.org) platform provides a test adapter for MSTest. You can then run your tests with any runner supporting Gallio, including built-in runners such as [Echo](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:echo) or [Icarus](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:icarus), and 3rd party runners such as [TD.Net](http://www.testdriven.net/) or [R#](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

The non-GUI test runners are usually slightly faster. Thus you may want to try [Echo](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:echo) or the [PoSh snap-in](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:powershell_snapin).

Comment: Using the Resharper test runner to run MSTest unit tests is fairly fast.  Faster than the VS test runner I think.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to integrate NUnit into TFS with some custom build tasks [(which some people have done)](http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/). If you really wanted to get crazy you could transform NUnit test results into .TRX files and import them directly using the [MSTEST command line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Cool idea, but that project has not been updated for almost a year.  (And I would need to do it with TFS 2010)  I guess I could roll my own, but I am not sure I would be able to get time for it approved.  So I would have to do it on my own time, and I am not sure it is worth that (I have so many other projects that keep me busy in my own dev time).

Comment: Even without the custom build tasks, you can always just run an executable as a build step. Plenty of people online have come up with ways to convert NUnit output into .TRX files. At that point you can import them directly into TFS and tie it directly to a build.

Answer (score 1):

TestDriven.Net is probably the fastest one.
Then goes msTest runner embedded into Visual Studio.

I found that ReSharper test runner is slower than built-in, especially if the solution is big.
At the time I was researching, ReSharper seemed to do a full rebuild of the solution, where msTest was just building changed projects.

So your best choice would be TestDriven.Net

Answer (score 0):

Albacore has an MSTest task.

https://github.com/derickbailey/Albacore/wiki/MSTest-Task

You could write a simple rake file that built your project and then ran the MSTest task.

My recommendation is that, initially, you write a project to only run the albacore MSTest task and time how long that takes.

PS: I wouldn't use Gallio because, in my experience, that test runner takes 6 seconds longer than TestDriven.net to run NUnit tests.
PS 2: My real recommendation is to ditch MSTest for xUnit.net or NUnit