# Spec Flow Setup Delay

Tags: .net, testing, mstest, specflow

I have a massive delay in running the test before it actually executes.  When I debug a test using MSTest runner within the 'Background' => 'Given' section between the .feature file and actually hitting the binding there is delay.  I've attached an ANTS profiler on to the QT agent and can see a lot of reflection going on.

This problem goes away when I use NUnit.

Has anyone encountered this problem??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that, i finally got to the bottom of it....

Changed the Spec Flow runner to use VisualStudio2012 runner

Added a .runsettings file with deployment item set to false, then selected this file.
.Testsettings file has performance issues i found out on MSDN site.

Also had to turn off MSTest support in Resharper

After that happy days no more 10 min delay, hope someone else finds this useful!

Answer (score 0):

I my experience the Test runner included with VS takes an age to start tests up. this is not just Specflow but for any unit tests written in MSTest.  You are [not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661155/is-there-an-ms-test-runner-that-is-faster) who has noticed this. There is a [connect issue already](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768230/slow-running-in-test-runner)

[This question has a proposed fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541411/visual-studio-2012-slow-unit-testing), which I have not used, but just never use the built in test runner any more, preferring the ReSharper (faster) or NCrunch runners (fastest).